# C# How to convert a list of strings with not a single character to char?

Tags: c#, string, char, valueconverter

I have list of strings which has such items inside - 65,66... so on.

When I'm trying to use `Convert.ToChar(item)`, I'm getting error that single string should have only one character. What I can't understood is what I can really use besides the `Convert` function to turn 65 (string) into `char = A` value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<char> Alphabet = new List<char>();
        List<string> Message = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++)
        {
            Alphabet.Add((char)i);
        }
        var stroke = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        foreach (var letter in stroke)
        {
            if (Alphabet[Alphabet.Count - 1] == letter)
            {
                Message.Add((66.ToString()));
            }
            if (Alphabet[Alphabet.Count - 2] == letter)
            {
                Message.Add((65.ToString()));
            }
            if (Convert.ToChar(" ") == letter)
            {
                Message.Add(" ");
            }
            foreach (var item in Alphabet)
            {

                if (item == letter && letter != Alphabet[Alphabet.Count -1] && letter != Alphabet[Alphabet.Count - 2])
                {
                    Message.Add((item + 2).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in Message)
        {
            if (item != " ")
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt16(item)));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();}
```

Here is ending working code, for those who may wonder why i need such type of convert.Its Caesarus encrypter. Working only for upper-case letters but its working now with all help of those guys above.

Comment: Convert to an int, then to a char. If you convert a string to a char it expects a single, individual character.

Comment: @sab669 - [ToChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3ew98y(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @sab669 ty for wise comment, you answered for my question. Now i have working Caesarus encrypter.

Comment: @Amit `var num = "65"; var letter = Convert.ToChar(num);` will crash at run time. In their example, they use the unicode value (note the single quotes) representing a tab. That's why they cast it to a string in the assignment; because it's a string array, not a char array.

Comment: @sab669 - Actually you're right. The quick description in the documentation threw me off: *Converts the first character of a specified string to a Unicode character.*. That's just terrible.

Comment: I suspect my terminology used was incorrect in regards to the tab character, though. If so, someone please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If items of your list are int values such as 65,66, ... that seems to be character codes, you can try:

```
Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(item))
```

For example:

```
var str="65";
var chr= Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(str));
//The output is A
```

Comment: Yeah ty, @sab669 help me in comment section above. Its realy hard to find usage of Function inside other Function.

Comment: @StrangerOnTheStorm you can see the sample in answer

Comment: @StrangerOnTheStorm "Nested" function calls are just like HTML; the first one you open is the last one you close. The inner-most method call is executed first, so it'll convert `item` to an `int`, then the `int` value to a `char`. While it can look ugly from a readability standpoint, it's actually quite simple :)

Comment: @sab669 i`m new here, may i wonder how question rating is working here. If i have more complicated question it will get more points? I could not find an answer in google for my language section so i decide to use this site.

Comment: @StrangerOnTheStorm other users vote question or answers up/down based on their opinion about being good question/answer.

Comment: @StrangerOnTheStorm Two main things; Include the actual exception; most importantly the type and the message. Secondly, the apparent lack of attempt to solve it first. For something fairly basic like this, Googling the exception or some basic terminology related to what you're trying ("convert string to char C#") should likely push you in the right direction. If not, include what you've tried / read in your post so others can see you've made an attempt to solve it. Most people on SO are more than happy to help, if you've shown you've tried your best first.

Comment: @StrangerOnTheStorm by the way here in StackOverFlow when you find an answer helpful you can kindly click the check mark at the left side of answer to accept it as answer, You can only accept one answer but you can vote as many answer as you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption:

```
var stroke = Console.ReadLine();
var enc = new String(stroke.ToCharArray().Select(c=>Convert.ToChar(c+2)).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(enc);
```

Comment: Its a good shortcut, but what if i write z does it show me it like b or not?

Comment: It doesn't.  That is fairly easy to add.